# Role based authorization in flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I need to introduce role-based authorization in existing Flask application. Because of that I can't just swap currently used flask-login package with flask-user for example. Nevertheless I have to restrict access to some endpoints to "admin" users without rebuilding entire code base.

I came up with a decorator like this:

```
def admin_required(func):
    """
    Modified login_required decorator to restrict access to admin group.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.group != 0:        # zero means admin, one and up are other groups
            flash("You don't have permission to access this resource.", "warning")
            return redirect(url_for("main.home"))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

I use it with original `login_required` decorator like so:

```
@app.route("/admin-restricted"):
@login_required
@admin_required
def admin_resource():
    return "Hello admin"
```

Everything works as expected BUT I have two concerns:

1. Is my method safe? Have I missed something which is potential security flaw? Unfortunately I have limited knowledge about Flask internals.
2. Is there more simple/safe/pythonic way to do that? It just doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more common method of dealing with role based permissions is to use Flask Principal.

In the main app:

```
from flask_principal import Principal

# load the extension
principals = Principal(app)

@identity_loaded.connect_via(app)
def on_identity_loaded(sender, identity):
    # Set the identity user object
    identity.user = current_user
    # Add the UserNeed to the identity
    if hasattr(current_user, 'employee_id'):
        identity.provides.add(UserNeed(current_user.employee_id))

    # Assuming the User model has a list of roles, update the
    # identity with the roles that the user provides
    if hasattr(current_user, 'position'):
        # for role in current_user.role:
        identity.provides.add(RoleNeed(str(current_user.position)))

   admin_permission = Permission(RoleNeed('admin'))
```

And then in the route:

```
@app.route("/admin-restricted"):
@login_required
@admin_permission.require(http_exception=403)
def admin_resource():
    return "Hello admin"
```

Docs: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/

Comment: That's cool. I've read documentation a bit and only one thing isn't obvious to me. Is there easy way to `flash` a message and `redirect` somewhere instead of throwing 403?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to extend the functionality but I admittedly took the easier approach and rather than use the decorator, I replaced it with this in the first line of the view function: `if not admin_permission.require().can():` then flash and redirect. You can make a custom decorator that wraps the Flask-Principal logic. Here's an example of a custom decorator you can model after to accomplish the desired effect: https://gist.github.com/ryan-hallman/c6fa18d6847ef06d548f8de94ec29102